# How a CNN interprets an image with a CMYK color scheme?

Tags: conv-neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I already know the following

- If the image is grayscale it will be interpretted as a 2D array with a height and width
- If the image is in RGB colour schem it will be interpretted as a 3D array with height, width and depth

My question is what is the arrangement when it comes to an image with a CMYK color scheme? I have never seen this is beign explained in my learning materials. So I am curious.

I haven't tried a CNN with a CMYK image.

Comment: It would just be a 4 channel image, and it would be interpreted exactly like that.

Comment: Thaks for the answer, so it would be a 3D array with 4 channels, am I right?